# PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey не читает ключ

Tags: c, rsa

Подобных тем много, но ошибку исправить не смог.
Проблема в следующем:
создаю *RSA*-ключи и записываю в *key* файлы.

```
rsa = RSA_generate_key(bits, RSA_F4, NULL, NULL);
unsigned char passw[]="secret";
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname("bf-ofb");
if (!PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(privKey_file, rsa, cipher, passw, NULL, NULL, NULL))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "PEM_write_PrivateKey failed.\n");

    iRet = EXIT_FAILURE;
}   
if (!PEM_write_RSAPublicKey(pubKey_file, rsa))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "PEM_write_PublicKey failed.\n");

    iRet = EXIT_FAILURE;
}
RSA_free(rsa);
```

Другой программой читаю приватный ключ:

```
RSA* pRSAPRI = RSA_new();
RSA * privKey = NULL;
char secret[] = "secret";
FILE * privKey_file;
unsigned char *ptext, *ctext;
int inlen, outlen;

privKey_file = fopen("private.key", "r");
if (privKey_file == NULL) {

    printf("fopen error \n");
    return -1;
}
printf("file opened\n");

privKey = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(privKey_file, NULL, NULL, secret);
if (privKey == NULL) {

    printf("Load key error\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Так вот, при запуске из командной строки выдает:

> ```
> file opened
> load key error
> ```

При отладке в vc 2017 показывает, что `privKey_file` равен `NULL`!
Подскажите, почему разные результаты с `fopen` и почему не читается ключ?

Comment: Цитата из документации:
"For the PEM write routines if the kstr parameter is not NULL then klen bytes at kstr are used as the passphrase and cb is ignored." у вас задан kstr (который secret), но его длина указана нулевой. Подозреваю, проблема где-то тут...

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Проблема в этом параметре.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в этой строке:

```
PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(privKey_file, rsa, cipher, passw, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

В документации сказано:

> For the PEM write routines if the kstr parameter is not NULL then klen bytes at kstr are used as the passphrase and cb is ignored.

У вас в kstr передается ваш passw. А вот следующий за ним klen установлен в ноль, хотя там должна быть длина пароля.